# Create Drupal user from donation pages?

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

We have one donation page that is just for donations. No Drupal account is created.  Individual members can create free accounts on the D7 site and can also donate through CiviCRM - this part is working as intended.

We want to build a second donation page where a Drupal user account is created.  I was assuming there would be a simple way to enable the username and password inputs, and set a Drupal role to enable, on a particular donation page so the D7 account could be created when the form is submitted, but I don't see how to do this.

Is there a way to either require an account be created, or allow it to be an option from a donation page?

The goal here is to automate the process of setting up corporate sponsors.  Sponsors need to contribute and have a Drupal 7 account created with a specific role so they can access content that is restricted to that role.  They should be able to select a specific package or enter an amount they wish to contribute.

Thanks,
Rachel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to add a profile to the contribution page with `Account creation required` enabled.

To do this -

- Check for the profile added to your contribution page on `Profiles` tab from `Manage Contritbuion Pages` or by visiting `civicrm/admin/contribute/custom?action=update&reset=1&id=<page_id>`
- Navigate to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Profiles.
- Click on `Settings` link for the profile added to your contribution page (Create if no profile is added).
- Open `Advanced Settings` tab and look for the `Drupal user account registration option?` input field.
- Enable `Account creation required` and navigate to the contribution page to see the populated drupal username field.

Comment: Thank you!  Adding a blank profile with "Account creation required" to the contribution page does indeed add just the username and password fields. Is it possible to add a specific Drupal role immediately or does that need to be done via sync?

Comment: Could be done via `rules` or need to do some code customisation in the extension.

Comment: rules == drupal Rules module